# Upstart - unable ro read /etc/shadow unelss sudo

Tags: linux, upstart

In the following script in `Upstart`, I'm unable to read `/etc/shadow` in `pre-script` phase, unless I use `$(echo mypass | sudo -S cat /etc/shadow | grep myusername)`

The script works fine if I provide my sudo pass, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without having to write my pass in the conf file?

## node-example.conf

```
description     "Starting Node with Upstart and Forever"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]

stop on runlevel [06]

expect fork

respawn 

respawn limit 5 30

console output

setuid myusername

env HOME=/home/myusername

env ARGS_FILE=/etc/shadow

. /etc/shadow

script

cd $HOME

exec forever start -a -l /tmp/forever.log -o /tmp/forever.stdout.log -e /tmp/forever.stderr.log --watch --watchDirectory /home/myusername/myapp/server /home/myusername/myapp/server/server.js

end script

pre-start script

ori='myusername:$6$P...'

# cur=$(echo mypass | sudo -S cat /etc/shadow | grep myusername) -> this works

cur=$(cat $ARGS_FILE | grep myusername) -> this doesn't work

if [ "$ori" = "$cur" ]

then encfs code

  else rm -rf somefile

fi

end script
```

Comment: Like yeah if you try to change a password or a username in a OS it will ask for sudo permission.

Comment: I thought Upstart scripts already have sudo permissions. I've tried with other files in /etc and I can't read any of them, unless I provide my sudo pass.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good reason why shadow is accessible only by root: Anybody who can change it can easily get root access. Given some time, oldish MD5 passwords can even be calculated. Bottom line: don't fiddle with `/etc/shadow` unless you absolutely have to. Basically, this reduces the need to changing passwords.

I am not too sure what you are trying to achieve, but doing a `grep $username /etc/passwd` should give you all information you need *except* for the hashed password.

And upstart scripts don't have to be run as root. It is perfectly fine to run a daemon as whichever user. This is achieved using the [setuid](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid) stanza (there is an according setgid). So you install the service as root and let it drop privileges.

Another option would be to use a [user-job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#user-job). Make sure you [enable user-jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#enabling).

Whatever you do : **Don't fiddle with `/etc/shadow`!**